# Where can we see the list of all shared albums on Google Plus?

Tags: google-plus, sharing, album

I can't find the page where I could see all the albums other users have given me access to on my Google+ albums photo https://plus.google.com/photos .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no special place for you to see all the albums from other users.

When you visit a profile's Photo-section you will see those albums that are shared either in Public or with circles you are in, or privately with you.

People can change their album settings any time.

[Photos section in my profile](https://plus.google.com/+JaanaNystr%C3%B6m/photos)

**Imagine this:**

I have been circled by over 466 000 profiles or pages. What if each of them has 10 Public albums?  That would just about crash the Interwebz if I started to list them all...  :-)

Comment: I guess I just need the `private share` with my specific G+ name, NOT via the circles I am in?

Comment: Going to the profile's photo section is what I'm looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It seems that a link like `https://plus.google.com/photos/+{NAME}/albums` works.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra the given link is not a link to an answer. It is the actual answer. That is where the albums are located.

Comment: This answers the question fully, thanks!

Comment: With Google+ shutting down, this URL will stop working too. Is there another way to share selected Google Photos Albums on a single web page?

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple. Just go to the the persons profile and just look through the hundreds and hundreds of photos and find that special photo album you wanted when the name pops up on the top.

Comment: Nice advice but not something we expect here on Web Applications.