# URL to the list of public Google Plus photo albums?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-photos, album

We share event photos with public through Google Plus photos. We <strike>can</strike> were able to directly give a link to an album, or to a list of available albums like this:

```
https://plus.google.com/photos/+(MyPage)/albums
```

But this link doesn't work anymore—it displays a link to new Google Photos where you need to log in.

Can anybody give a **link to the list of publicly shared photo albums on new Google Photos, which doesn't require the visitor to log in**?

**Note:**
I don't mean the highlights page which brings contents of all albums, rather than a simple list of albums:

```
https://plus.google.com/+MyPage/photos
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Google Plus has been retired.

Answer (score 3):

Since Google Plus is shutting down in April 2019, I was looking for a replacement to share multiple shared albums via one URL (one page). And the solution I found is this:

1. create a new site using https://sites.google.com
2. from the `Insert` pane, click `Embed`
3. in Google Photos,

   - open your shared album,
   - click the *share* icon,
   - click `Create link` and `Copy` the URL, which should look like `https:// goo.gl/photos/_hash_`
4. back on your new Site in the Insert/Embed dialog paste the URL of the album, it previews your thumbnail and you Insert it into the page.
5. Done.

Answer (score 1):

When you go through Google Photos (photos.google.com) you are able to create albums and share them with a publicly available URL that doesn't require an account. Your albums from Google+ should be there automatically.

Comment: But this only gives us public direct links to albums right? We are looking for a URL to a list of our publicly available albums, so a visitor can browse albums with names and cover thumbnails, without requiring a link for each one. We've temporarily switched to the highlights page.

Comment: I'm unable to verify, but it looks like this might have been answered here:

http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/45600/where-can-we-see-the-list-of-all-shared-albums-on-google-plus

Comment: Thank you. I've seen that question. OP asks for a URL to list 'albums shared by others with him/her'. And one of the answers states the URL pattern I've already written in my question, which I've used for years and doesn't work now.

Answer (score -2):

We have exactly the same problem. For now we solved with https://plus.google.com/+PAGENAME/photos which I know you don't like.

Another possibility is to go through Picasa: https://picasaweb.google.com/PAGE_ID

But if you find better solution, I'd like to know about it.